# Receiving attribute error 'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute '_get_firefox_output'

Tags: python, firefox, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On Wednesday, my code worked. I return today, and my code no longer works. No one has touched it, not including myself. I'm receiving the following error message:

```
'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute '_get_firefox_output'
```

I'm using the SST framework for Selenium/Python. My code doesn't call out directly the browser.py file, as I'm only calling actions, cases and config. I've uninstalled and reinstalled both SST and Firefox, with the same results.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config

class TestMyTest(cases.SSTTestCase):

   def test_mytestcase_home_page(self):
        config.results_directory = "C:/Users/Brenda/test/SST-Test-Project/results"
        go_to('http://www.myhomepage.com')
        assert_title_contains('My Home Page')
        take_screenshot(filename='home_page.png',add_timestamp=True)
        assert_element(tag='a', text='Log in')
```

I have downgraded Firefox from 34.0.5 to 32. I am running python 2.7.8. I am also running SST 0.2.4. The full traceback error message is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Brenda/test/SST-Test-Project/MySSTTest.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_mytestcase_home_page (__main__.TestMyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
_StringException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 75, in setUp
    self.start_browser()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 102, in start_browser
    self._start_browser()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 95, in _start_browser
    self.browser = self.browser_factory.browser()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\browsers.py", line 211, in browser
    return self.webdriver_class(self.profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\browsers.py", line 183, in __init__
    firefox_profile, FirefoxBinary(), timeout, capabilities, proxy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in      __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sst\browsers.py", line 172, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self._get_firefox_output(),))
AttributeError: 'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute '_get_firefox_output'
```

Comment: Is the path to the binary valid and accessible?

Comment: It should be. I have not changed anything.

Comment: Ok, what selenium and python version are you using? Is this inside a virtual environment or it is a system python? Thanks.

Comment: SST is 0.2.4 (latest) and python is 2.7.8. As far as I know, I'm running the most recent version of selenium (2.44)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, what about firefox, which version are you using?

Comment: 34.0.5. I just uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Comment: Okay, now we can try to make conclusions. My working theory is that it is a version compatibility problem which was caused by automatic firefox update. First, try to downgrade firefox to 33 (or 32).

Comment: I downgraded to 32 and it is still throwing the error.

Comment: Okay, please provide a complete error traceback you are getting. As a side note, please edit the question and move all the information I've asked you about to the question itself - this would help others to help you faster. Thanks.

Comment: I have made the updates

Comment: Okay, let's try another theory: may be SST and selenium versions are not compatible - try to downgrade selenium to 2.43, for starters. Thanks.

Comment: It threw an error message when attempting to install selenium 2.43.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

<sup>(taken from [Learn to Read the Source, Luke](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/))</sup>

After exploring the source code of `selenium` python bindings, I've found out that in [selenium `2.44`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py?name=selenium-2.44.0#92) there is no more `_get_firefox_output()` method available in a `FirefoxBinary` class. As opposed to version `2.43` which [contained it](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py?name=selenium-2.43.1#92):

```
def _get_firefox_output(self):
    return self.process.communicate()[0]

def _wait_until_connectable(self):
    """Blocks until the extension is connectable in the firefox."""
    count = 0
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
        if self.process.poll() is not None:
            # Browser has exited
            raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
                  "before we could connect. The output was: %s" %
                  self._get_firefox_output())
        if count == 30:
            self.kill()
            raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
                  "Dir: %s Firefox output: %s" % (
                      self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    return True
```

In other words, **`SST 0.2.4` is not compatible with selenium `2.44`**. Downgrade `selenium` to `2.43`.

Comment: Thank you. I have one problem. What do I enter in the pip install to get 2.43.0 specifically?

Comment: @Brenda yeah, you said it was giving you an error, are you doing `pip install selenium==2.43`?

Comment: Thank you. I had missed the "==" in the line.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Your answer worked for me on our Ubuntu machine but -- as you'll see from my "Answer" -- `selenium==2.44.0` is, at least *sometimes*,  compatible with `sst==0.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... there is something else going on here. Not really an answer but ... please see highlighted code below.

I have `sst==0.2.4` test working  with `selenium==2.44.0`  on my Mac but only  @alecxe's answer (go back to `selenium==2.43.0` many thanks) got my tests working on our headless CI test machine. Both at Python 2.7.6; Firefox 34

#### Mac test

```
$ sst-run -x -d mytests
starting virtual display...Tests running...
    DEBUG:SST:Starting browser (attempt: 1)
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 7424 with port: 53449, count 1
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 7424 with port: 53449, count 2
    DEBUG:SST:Browser started: firefox
    DEBUG:SST:Going to... http://www.ubuntu.com/
    DEBUG:SST:Waiting for 'get_element'
    DEBUG:SST:Stopping browser
mytests.foo ... OK (3.487 secs)
Ran 1 test in 3.487s
OK
stopping virtual display...
(selenium-simple-test)iainhouston@iain-macbook:~/Documents/web/PyProjects/selenium-simple-test
$ pip freeze
    argparse==1.3.0
    extras==0.0.3
    junitxml==0.7
    python-mimeparse==0.1.4
    python-subunit==1.0.0
    selenium==2.44.0
    six==1.9.0
    sst==0.2.4
    testtools==1.5.0
    unittest2==0.8.0
    wsgiref==0.1.2
```

#### Ubuntu headless server test

Whereas previously, with `Found existing installation: selenium 2.44.0` I was getting `AttributeError: 'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute '_get_firefox_output'`; after `pip install selenium==2.43` the tests worked.

```
(testENV)iain@jude:~/selenium_simple_test$ sst-run -x -d mytests
starting virtual display...Tests running...
    DEBUG:SST:Starting browser (attempt: 1)
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 4023 with port: 42899, count 1
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 4023 with port: 42899, count 2
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 4023 with port: 42899, count 3
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 4023 with port: 42899, count 4
    DEBUG:SST:Browser started: firefox
    DEBUG:SST:Going to... http://www.ubuntu.com
    DEBUG:SST:Waiting for 'get_element'
    DEBUG:SST:Stopping browser
mytests.tests ... OK (5.951 secs)
Ran 1 test in 5.951s
OK
stopping virtual display...
(testENV)iain@jude:~/selenium_simple_test$ pip freeze
    argparse==1.2.1
    extras==0.0.3
    junitxml==0.7
    python-mimeparse==0.1.4
    python-subunit==1.0.0
    selenium==2.43.0
    six==1.9.0
    sst==0.2.4
    testtools==1.5.0
    unittest2==0.8.0
    wsgiref==0.1.2
```